# What is a Haar Distribution in matrix algebra

Tags: matrices, invariance, haar-measure

There are a lot of places explaining Haar Distribution but they require some basics of Borel fields, Lie fields, etc. I am not a math major, so I do not have exposure to these concepts.

Here is my understanding of Haar distribution:

**Take a $N×N$ matrix, say $M$, of i.i.d. standard Gaussian random variables.One can take a QR decomposition of $M$ and get an orthogonal Matrix $Q$. People claim that the matrix $Q$ is a Haar measure over O(N).**

**A key property:  $Q$is left-invariant, meaning, for any $R∈O(N)$,  $Q$and $RQ$ have the same distribution.**

What is the proof of this invariance property? ( in terms of matrix algebra, if possible)

Comment: It comes down to the rotational symmetry of the standard Gaussian distribution.  Each column of $M$ is a Gaussian vector, and if you premultiply $M$ by a non random orthogonal matrix $R$, the distribution of the columns is not changed.  But the columns are independent, so the joint distribution of the columns is not changed, either.  That is, the distribution of $RM$ is the same as that of $M$.

Comment: You may find [this](https://nhigham.com/2020/04/22/what-is-a-random-orthogonal-matrix) interesting